# Update a table use result of another query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have a 2 table like this:

**table1**: (*time, value, id*) , **table2**:(*time, value, id, ...*)

I need to update **table1** with a result of a query on **table2** based on **id**,
for example the query can be:

```
SELECT * from table2 where value > 2
```

and this query returns more than hundreds of rows,

I need update `table1` with these rows based on `id` (`set time=q.time, value=q.value where id=q.id`) is it possible with sql query?

I don't need UPSERT as I'm sure I have same id in both tables, just need update

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 4):

Postgres supports a `FROM` clause for [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html):

```
update table1
   set time = q.time, 
       value = q.value
from table2 q
where table2.id = table1.id
  and table2.value > 2;
```

Comment: simple and precise.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
into temp buffer     
from table2 
where value > 2;


insert into table1(list of columns to be updated)
select (list of columns to be selected)
from buffer;
```

NOTE___
--buffer is a temporary table that stores the output of the main query
-- make sure both tables (table1 and table2) have the same columns and are arranged in the same order